# How to ignore/resolve svn tree conflicts when merging to branch with folders deleted on purpose?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging, tree-conflict

In one of my branches I deleted some folders on purpose which contain plug-in sources that shouldn't be available for most of the developers using this branch. When merging new revisions from trunk to branch, i am always getting tree conflicts which i just resolve.

How can I tell svn (TortoiseSVN 1.7.6) to just ignore these deleted folders and tree conflicts in the future to speed up my merging process?

Comment: When you say you are resolving the conflicts every time you merge how are you actually doing this? Do you accept the local changes as authoritative? If so you shouldn't then get the same conflicts again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, at least not automatically.

You can, however, merge the revision/s containing the deletes from your branch into trunk so that trunk knows that those folders are deleted. Then, when you merge from trunk up into other branches, the change will ripple across into them.

When you need to merge the original branch back into trunk, you will either need to cherry-pick the revisions you want to merge, except the ones containing the deletes (sequential merge) or perform a differential merge. A third option is to do a reintegration merge, but (if you're planning to continue working on the branch) you should delete and then recreate the branch post-merge to avoid weird merge issues involving that branch later on.

Hope this helps.